# Looking up a value and multiplying a column based on column name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

First question so bear with me if I'm not asking well. I have a dataset that contains data in different units (ie ppb and ppm); I need to standardize all the data to the same units, but not all the columns need converting.

I've created a simple table, read from a csv:

```py
param=pd.read_csv('InputParamssimple.csv')
```

| Index | Column | Multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10570 | 1000 |
| 1 | 11970 | 1 |
| 2 | 20570 | 1000 |
| 3 | 21970 | 1 |

Ultimately this table will have more rows with more information to reference (Name, data type, etc) for creating plots and the like.

Sample data, also read from a csv:

```py
df=pd.read_csv('InputTest.csv')
```

| Index | Unnamed: 0 | Unnamed: 1 | 10570 | 11970 | 20570 | 21970 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 45108.00000 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 14 |
| 1 | 2 | 45108.04167 | 2 | 6 | 11 | 15 |
| 2 | 3 | 45108.08333 | 3 | 7 | Z | 16 |
| 3 | 4 | 45108.12500 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 17 |
| 4 | 5 | 45108.16667 | Z | 9 | 13 | 18 |

Unnamed columns are an index and a datetime that come over from the source database.

I process the data to convert the text values to NaN

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

which yields

| Index | Unnamed: 0 | Unnamed: 1 | 10570 | 11970 | 20570 | 21970 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 45108.00000 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 14 |
| 1 | 2 | 45108.04167 | 2 | 6 | 11 | 15 |
| 2 | 3 | 45108.08333 | 3 | 7 | NaN | 16 |
| 3 | 4 | 45108.12500 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 17 |
| 4 | 5 | 45108.16667 | NaN | 9 | 13 | 18 |

Here is where I'm stuck. I need to apply the appropriate multiplier to each column (570's get multiplied by 1000, 1970's are unchanged). My attempt to apply a lambda during the error coercion seems to do absolutely nothing, returning the same dataset back:

```py
for col in df.columns:

        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x*param.loc[param['Column']==df[col],'Multiplier'])
```

df.info() after conversion of text returns:

```
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   Unnamed: 0  5 non-null      int64  
 1   Unnamed: 1  5 non-null      float64
 2   10570       5 non-null      object 
 3   11970       5 non-null      int64  
 4   20570       5 non-null      object 
 5   21970       5 non-null      int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(3), object(2)
```

Which suggests the columns that had to_numeric applied did not actually become a numeric type? Is this why my lambda is failing or is there something else happening here I don't understand? I would prefer to not have to sort either data set and be able to do an Excel style index/match operation. I would also prefer to not have to do anything to the Unnamed columns, but they could be assigned names in the early steps if required.

Thoughts are appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Made it all readable.